# help with making this mysql query into a PDO query

Tags: php, pdo

I have been using this for a while, but have since then upgraded to PDO instead of mysql queries. But I can't seem to get this particular snippet to work at all.

```
$query = mysql_query ($sql) or die (mysql_error());
while ($records = @mysql_fetch_array ($query)) {
    $alpha[$records['alpha']] += 1;
    ${$records['alpha']}[$records['id_clients']] = array(
        $records['first_name'],       //item[0]
    );
}
```

I have tried this

```
while ($records = $this->db->fetch_row_assoc($sql)) {
    $alpha[$records['alpha']] += 1;
    ${$records['alpha']}[$records['id_clients']] = array(
        $records['first_name'],       //item[0]
    );
}
```

and my PDO code is

```
public function query($statement)
    {
        return self::$PDO->query($statement);
    }
public function fetch_row_assoc($statement) {
    self::$PDO->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
        try
        {
            $stmt = self::$PDO->query($statement); 
            $result = $stmt->fetch();
            return $result;
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
        return false;
        //return self::$PDO->query($statement)->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    }
```

The query function works, but I have introduced my fetch_row_assoc function in hopes that I can do that same thing with mysql_fetch_asso.

```
$sql = "SELECT 
                    SUBSTRING(`last_name`, 1, 1) AS alpha,
                    SUBSTRING(`middle_name`, 1, 1) AS subMiddleName,
                    `id_clients`,
                    `type`,
                    `first_name`,
                    `middle_name`,
                    `last_name`,
                    `address`,
                    `primary_number`,
                    `secondary_number`,
                    `home_number`,
                    `office_number`,
                    `cell_number`,
                    `fax_number`,
                    `ext_number`,
                    `other_number`,
                    `comments`
                FROM `clients`
                WHERE `user_id` = 1
                AND `is_sub` = 0
                AND `prospect` = 1
                ORDER BY `last_name`";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public function query($statement)
    {
        return self::$PDO->query($statement);
    }
public function fetch_row_assoc($statement) {
    self::$PDO->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
        try
        {
            $stmt = self::$PDO->query($statement); 
            $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $result = $stmt->fetch();
            return $result;
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: my problem is that it takes longer than 60 seconds to do the query and times out on my server with an error msg: Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in /var/www/vhosts/foo.bar/httpdocs/library/classes/database.class.php on line 115

Comment: could you post the actual query? I don't think the timeout occurs because of the PHP code.

Comment: The query appears to be ok. I would continue the investigation with trying to call the fetch_row_assoc method with a dead simple SQL query like `SELECT 1 AS foobar;` and see if it works well. If it does, then the method is OK, and the problem lies elsewhere. I'd be very surprised if the 60 sec-exceeding execution time is because of the PHP code.

Comment: actually let me update you on what i found, its pointing to this line of code that takes long to execute:$alpha[$records['alpha']] += 1; I did simplify my query for to see if it was that. But now after only selecting 3 fields I am able to get this error